# Mass transfer approval process

Tags: apex, visualforce, class

In our case, usually the users request us the approvals pending of a particular user. We go to Setup ->  Administration Setup  -> Data Management -> Mass Transfer Approval Processes and we manage multiple pending approval requests.
Is it possible that we can create a page or so that a user without salesforce license can see these approvals.

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible to a user without a sales force license to see the approval request

Comment: Mahesh, your answer is rather short and doens't explain itself. Would you be able to update it with more detail or any official refernce (documentation) to back up what you're saying ?